# Takin Screen Shot of video playing on Android device using Android view client

Tags: python, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

Taking snap shot is very simple using Android view client in monkeyrunner tool . 
My problem is >
I am working on an Android TV . And i m automating one app for channel installation . 
Now i Tv have different On Screen Displays (OSD) where android apps are displayed on different OSD and Video is played on another OSD.

When i take the snap shot i get blank picture , most probably because of the OSD issue.

Can anybody please suggest me , if there is any way to take the screen shot of the video .

If i m not clear enough please let me know.

Thanks